# What is this capacitor?

Tags: identification, electrolytic-capacitor

Can anyone confirm what the markings on this capacitor mean?

I think it's a 560 μF capacitor, but I am used to seeing that on the first row of similar devices.

For voltage, I believe it's a 35 V device - the V matches what I see here: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/capacitor-codes-markings.php

What is the first row, and what does the ZR denote?

Oddly labelled electrolytic capacitor:

[image]

Comment: 56uF it seems. Aluminum electrolytic, SMT. Hard to get a sense of the exact size

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a part with similar characteristics to Nichicon ZR series, but not actually Nichicon since the number placement does not match Nichicon's datasheet.

ZR is the series
V is the voltage code (35V)
56uF or 560uF is the capacitance. Compare with similar size parts with 35V rating- if it is similar or a bit smaller compared to known name brands it's likely that.

A typical 35V/470uF is 10mm dia x 10.5mm tall

A typical 35V/680uF is 12.5mm dia x 13.5mm tall

If it's in that size range it's probably 560uF.

(another manufacturer has 35V/560uF that is 10mm dia x 13mm tall)

If that's an M3 or M4 screw the capacitor is pretty large.

Both types of markings are common enough in SMT caps.

The top markings are a lot code.

Comment: Are you sure? Why not 56µF?

Comment: @G36 Good point, probably 56uF unless it's huge given the voltage. Neither 560uF/35V or 56uF/35V is offered by Nichicon in their ZR series.

Comment: wouldn't 56uF be 566 ?

Comment: @Jasen no, they're either 2+multiplier code in uF or integer uF. That's on electrolytic caps, many other types are in pF as you suggest. It's a bit of a dog's breakfast, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.  I appreciate the confirmation of the voltage rating in particular, as I wasn't able to validate that.

I was able to measure the capacitance... got a reading of 599uF (in circuit).  There are no other large caps on the board so it must be rated 560uF.  It looks like it is 10-12mm in diameter and similar height, so right in line with the two measurements that Spehro provided.

Comment: Unless you are using an impedance analyzer, measuring in-circuit will often give a wrong reading.

Comment: Yes I know it's not perfect.  If the choices are 56*10^0 and 560, the 599 definitely seems to imply the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a 56 μF 35 V electrolytic capacitor with a height of 3.9 mm.

Marking codes:

1. Value - 1st significant figure, 2nd significant figure, multiplier

   Multiplier

   0 - 1

   1 - 10

   2 - 100

   3 - 1000

   4 - 10000

   5 - 100000

   6 - 1000000
2. Voltage

   e - 2.5 V

   G - 4 V

   J - 6.3 V

   A - 10 V

   C - 16 V

   D - 20 V

   E - 25 V

   V - 35 V

   H - 50 V
3. Height

   ZD - 3 mm

   ZR - 3.9 mm